# sql error when installing a module

Tags: 7, database

after enabling raydash module the message appear
`PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The session id foreign key',`token`VARCHAR(32) NOT' at line 4: CREATE TABLE {raydash_stream} (`nid`INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'The table for the stream',`entity_id`INT unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment COMMENT 'The entity in the video stream that\ncoresponds to the token',`session_id`VARCHAR(128) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'The session id foreign key',`token`VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,`connected_token`VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL COMMENT 'The token this video-stream is connected', PRIMARY KEY (`nid`,`entity_id`,`session_id`) ) ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COMMENT 'The table stores video stream'; Array ( ) in db_create_table() (line 2684 of C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal\includes\database\database.inc)`.
How to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The Raydash module (if it's [this one](https://github.com/gersh/raydash-drupal)) appears to be a sandbox project that isn't even hosted on Drupal.org.

Sandbox projects are not suitable for production use and usually have a number of bugs; this is what makes them sandbox projects rather than real modules on Drupal.org.

Also, the Raydash module I linked to only had one commit a year ago.  Drupal 7 has changed some since then so it's unlikely that this module would still work "out of the box" if it ever did.

I would disable the module for now and either:

- Consider forking the module and fixing it yourself (giving back the patches if you succeed) or

or

- Looking for a different solution.

Comment: i looked for another solution but i did not find any thing yet.i just want to add a live camera to a node can you give me any suggestions.

Comment: Sorry, that question is unrelated to your original question and I don't know the answer.  To increase the chance of getting a good answer, you should ask that as a separate question.